# Reusable Component

Tags: api, module

I want to create a reusable component and looking for best approach expert may say

```
1. As a Web Service
2. Building using native component like jar in Java
3. Others
```

I Understood that each method has own pros and cons but thinking about too much request call in case of exposing it as API.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are apps that your system uses but it can be used from other systems. The plus with web services is the versioning. Always will have the last version and always will manage your version in one place.

The jar or libraries can have access to machine and machine resources (web services don't) is faster that web services but you cannot use them out of your system.

Also the big difference between them is that you cannot compile a hole application built with "jars" in your PC you don't have the ram and CPU that why we use service and micro-server ...

So if you want to build some small and only for a service, use the jar - libs.

If you want to build something bigger and it may will use from another systems and you want to be scalable etc use services or micro services

Comment: Lets take small example that Sign Up is required for each and every application we built in real world i.e which just captures username and password and gets success or failure as response. In this case, will API or others method is good practice in your point of view?

Comment: The authentication and authorization MUST be implemented as web service (in 2017) with OAuth2

Comment: Yes, If we made as a service, should use any one of Authentication methods. In our case its an authentication to access this own application and not going to fetch any information from the service. It is kind of reusable code to reduce the efforts. Here too API is best approach or any reason to choose API approach on this?

Comment: In your case it the same pretty much. You should do it with service way and the reason is the scalability, stability, modularity. But if you want to do it fast and don't to mess with API calls use the lib way.